# How can I remove the required attribute in IE?

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

If a user selects #no-nonp-reg radio button, then #tax-num should be hidden, and not required. Here are the relevant code snippets:

HTML5:

```
<label>Is your group registered as a nonprofit/tax-exempt?</label>
    <input type="radio" id="yes-nonp-reg" name="nonpReg" value="yesNonpReg"  checked>Yes
    <input type="radio" id="no-nonp-reg" name="nonpReg" value="noNonpReg">No<br>

    <span class="no-break" id="tax-num-spn">
        <label for="tax-num">Please enter either a Federal EIN or State ID #:</label>
    <input id="tax-num" name="taxNum" type="text" pattern="[0-9]{8,}" required>
    </span><br>
```

JS:

```
$('#no-nonp-reg').click(function(){
    "use strict";
    $('#tax-num-spn').addClass('hidden');
    $('#tax-num').prop('required', false);
    $('#tax-num').val("");
});
```

I also tried:

```
$('#tax-num').removeAttr('required');
```

I also tried:

```
$('#tax-num').attr('required', false);
```

As is so often the case, works fine with Chrome & FF. IE still insists on requiring the field and will not accept the submission, although it does hide it!

Comment: Which version of IE are you testing against?

Comment: You're not closing your input field and not assigning required: `<input id="tax-num" name="taxNum" type="text" pattern="[0-9]{8,}" required>`

Answer (score 0):

Hey Check [this](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/301) link, you may get help from this ,

```
 if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 10) {
    $('#form_to_validate [required]').addClass('required').removeAttr('required');
 }
```